# Creating whatsapp client in thunkable app inventor

Tags: android, web, url, webview, whatsapp

I want to make a whatsapp web client for android using thunkable app inventor but in webview whenever I try to add the url web.whatsapp.com, it redirects me to whatsapp.com please help me if anyone knows the solution. Btw I am making this client so that I don't need to see ads from the others clients available on play store cuz I have two phones and I need whatsapp on both of them but whatsapp doesn't allow it.

Thanks

Comment: WhatsApp needs one main device and another device client for the main device.
he or she can use the Web WhatsApp when your main device, phone, added in WhatsApp.

Comment: can you explain this in a simple manner?